# check grid value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

`gridid = myGrid`

```
Name Status
aa   Open
bb   Close
```

I want to check weather in `Status` column there is `Open` status already present or not.

If yes then `alert("already there ")`

I tried like

```
  function CheckDraftStatus() {
   var index = $("#myGrid thead tr > *").filter(function () {
                  return 'Status' == $.trim($(this).text())
              }).index();

    $('#myGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').text(function (i, text) {
    if  ($.trim(text) == 'Open')  {return true;}             
    else {return false}
    });
}
```

correct me or any other code please?

Comment: Its working and you want a *compact and easy* solution or it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try using [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
var result = $("#myGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + "):contains('Open')");

return result.length > 0 ? true : false;
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6HT3/).

**UPDATE**: To use many `contains` you will have to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like:

```
var tds = $("#myGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ")");
tds.filter(":contains('Open')");
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6HT3/1/).

Comment: thanks but if I need to check for 2 or more values ? then how to do it in `contains` ?

Comment: I tried like this 
`var result = $("#myGrid tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + "):contains('Open'):contains('Close')");`
but not working :(